# How to use Paginate method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with a PaginatedList in a Web API project.

In the repository there's a method like:

```
public virtual PaginatedList<T> Paginate<TKey>(int pageIndex, int pageSize,
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate,
    params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = AllIncluding(includeProperties).OrderBy(keySelector);

    query = (predicate == null)
        ? query
        : query.Where(predicate);

    return query.ToPaginatedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

But, when I try to use it, like this:

```
var a = repository.Paginate<Region>(pageNo, pageSize, x => x.ID, null);
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to
>   'Domain.Entities.Dictionaries.Region'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are your sample is correct? your `Paginate` method has 4 parameters(ignoring params), but you are sanding just 3 in the sample call

Comment: Yes, U're right. It was just a mistake. I've already updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method signature has `TKey` that i suppose is a key for sorting, but in your call you are specifying the whole object `Region`, and then you specify `int` in the `keySelector`, so it can't compile it as it tries to use `int` type as `Region` type for `TKey`.

I suppose your sample should be:

```
repository.Paginate<int>(pageNo, pageSize, x => x.ID, null);
```

Generic type `T` i suppose is specified for the whole class, so it should be fine here to not specify it in the call, as repository instance is already generic specific.